# Windows Phone 7.1 Mango and NetworkStream. Is it included? any good alternatives?

Tags: sockets, networkstream, windows-phone-7

Is the NetworkStream class, not included in the Mango SDK?
It doesn't seem to be in the System.Net assembly but maybe it is somewhere else.
If it is not available (I wonder why) what would be a good alternative? Would the best way to go to just implement it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be in the [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) namespace, so I guess you're out of luck. If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say it wasn't included because `Stream` exposes blocking read/write methods and they preferred to exclude `NetworkStream` entirely rather than have them throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Having a stream also implies that you can use `StreamReader`, which wouldn't be true due to the lack of blocking read/writes.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. I didn't know that blocking read/write methods were not supported in Windows Phone. By any chance do you know why is this or have a reference where I can find more about it?

Comment: Actually there reference is the Socket object itself, which simply doesn't define the synchronous versions of the methods. As to the why, I believe they didn't want people blocking the UI thread (despite there being alternatives).

Comment: Yes you are right. I just noticed that. Only the async behavior of the socket class works. Thanks a lot, it is good to know.